# Rest api как получить материалы из категории?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь создать простое rest api на чистом php

index.php

```
<?php

header('Content-type: json/application');
require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';

$q = ($_GET['q']);
$params = explode('/', $q);

$type = $params[0];
$id = $params[1];

if($type === 'typs'){
  
  if(isset($id)){
    getTyp($connect, $id);
  } else{
    getTyps($connect);
  }
}

$categorie = $params[0];
$id = $params[1];

if($categorie === 'categories'){
  
  if(isset($id)){
    getCategorie($connect, $id);
  } else{
    getCategories($connect);
  }
}

?>
```

function.php

```
<?php

function getTyps($connect){
  $typs = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `w_types`");
    $typsList = [];
    while($typ = mysqli_fetch_assoc($typs)){
  $typsList[] = $typ;
    }
    echo json_encode($typsList);
}

function getTyp($connect, $id){
  $typ = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `w_types` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    
  if(mysqli_num_rows($typ) === 0){
    http_response_code(404);
    $res = [
    "status" => false,
    "message" => "Post not found"
    ];
    
    echo json_encode($res);
  }else{
    $typ = mysqli_fetch_assoc($typ);
        echo json_encode($typ);
  }
  
  
}

function getCategories($connect){
  $categories = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `w_faucetpay_categories`");
    $categoriesList = [];
    while($categorie = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)){
  $categoriesList[] = $categorie;
    }
    echo json_encode($categoriesList);
}

function getCategorie($connect, $id){
  $categorie = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `w_faucetpay_categories` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    
  if(mysqli_num_rows($categorie) === 0){
    http_response_code(404);
    $res = [
    "status" => false,
    "message" => "Post not found"
    ];
    
    echo json_encode($res);
  }else{
    $categorie = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categorie);
        echo json_encode($categorie);
  }
  
  
}

?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

По url site.ru/api/appfaucetlist/typs
я получаю все разделы.
По url site.ru/api/appfaucetlist/typs/1
я получаю один раздел.

По url site.ru/api/appfaucetlist/categories
я получаю все категории.
По url site.ru/api/appfaucetlist/categories/1
я получаю одну категорию.

А как мне быть если я хочу получить с одной категории, скажем /categories/1 все товары?

В бд есть две таблицы

w_categories с такими данными

id
type_id
title

w_list с такими данными

id
category_id
title

Где type_id это id раздела к которому относится категории, а category_id это id категории к которой относятся товары!

Comment: functions.php или function.php

Comment: Немного ошибся, правильно functions.php

Comment: На этом сайте принято задавать один вопрос, а не просить написать за тебя весь код, с SQL запросами и правкой конфига веб-сервера

Comment: Этот сайт был создан что бы на нём задавали эти вопросы. Мой второй вопрос относительно относиться полностью к первому вопросу, так как мне нужно получить товар по url

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, нужно получить товары из показываемой категории и также из вложенных в нее категорий.
Получаем категорию-родитель, затем получаем категории-дети, далее для каждой из полученных категории получаем списки товаров, объединяем списки и отображаем.
Кроме того, в index.php часть кода избыточна. Там можно обойтись вот таким кодом:

```
header('Content-type: json/application');
require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';

$q = ($_GET['q']);
$params = explode('/', $q);

$type = $params[0];
$id = $params[1];

if($type === 'typs'){
  if(isset($id)){
    getTyp($connect, $id);
  } else{
    getTyps($connect);
  }
}


if($type === 'categories'){    
  if(isset($id)){
    getCategorie($connect, $id);
  } else{
    getCategories($connect);
  }
}
```

UPD. Не забыть про htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  IndexIgnore */*
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php
</ifModule>
```

Comment: К примеру по url site.ru/api/categories/1 я получаю одну категорию по url site.ru/api/categories/1/1 я должен получить все товары у которых category_id это id этой категории. Конкретно в этом случае id = 1 а по url site.ru/api/categories/1/1/1 получить 1 товар из этой категории

Comment: Тогда айди товара надо ловить через $product_id = $params[2];

Comment: А как в htaccess сделать возможность создавать такого рода url? /categories/1/1/1

Comment: обновил ответ выше

Comment: Это добавить в мой файл или полностью заменить?

Comment: это отдельный файл под названием .htaccess, он будет перенаправлять ВСЕ урлы на index.php. Еще придется генерировать ответ 404, для НЕпредусмотренных тобою урлов, но это уже для другого вопроса.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос в который вложил свой .htaccess

Comment: Ну по идее все правильно, все должно работать. Или тебе весь проект с нуля написать?))))

Comment: С нуля  не нужно. В моём случае RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA] Если я заменяю полностью .htaccess то по ссылке /categories/1 я уже нечего не получаю

Comment: к вопросу о минусаторах. Ты что сказать-то хотел, вот этим вот своим `$key[$value];`? Мне даже интересно, что ты мог тут иметь в виду. мне ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: @Ипатьев Я был неправ. Моё поведение не достойно российского программиста. Я приношу свои извинения.